# Memoir headers with different font shapes

Tags: header-footer, memoir, small-caps

I'm using the `ruled` pagestyle under `Memoir` with small caps in the even page headers:

```
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\scshape\leftmark}{}{}
```

Is there a way to set only the title name in small caps and not the number in front of it. So if the header is "1. My chapter name" I want "My chapter name" in small caps but not "1."

Comment: I can't see any differences ;-): `\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\textsc{1.} vs. 1.
\end{document}`

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{tgpagella}` and `\textsc{3.} vs. 3.`

Comment: Maybe you should provide a complete MWE to avoid such guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine `chaptermark` which specifies the format of `\leftmark`:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \mbox{\normalfont\thechapter.}\ %
        \fi
      \fi
      #1}{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{My chapter name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```